# Strange behaviour on C array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I found really strange behaviour when looping through NSString array. The thing is it happens only in iOS 32bit environment, but on 64bit works as expected.

here is the code I run:

```
static NSString * const HexColors[3] = {
    @"FFFFFF",
    @"FF0000",
    @"000000"};

static NSString * const ColorDescription[3] = {
    @"white",
    @"red",
    @"black"};
```

in implementation file I loop as following

```
- (void)loop {
    NSInteger i = 0;
    while (HexColors[i]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", HexColors[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

The result I get:

```
2014-04-25 09:57:45.374 loopApp[587:60b] FFFFFF
2014-04-25 09:57:45.375 loopApp[587:60b] FF0000
2014-04-25 09:57:45.376 loopApp[587:60b] 000000
2014-04-25 09:57:45.376 loopApp[587:60b] white
2014-04-25 09:57:45.377 loopApp[587:60b] red
2014-04-25 09:57:45.377 loopApp[587:60b] black
```

And then app throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS on NSLog line

I could use "for" loop but this is not the case

Any idea why it happen? Is it the clang issue?

Comment: Instead of that use `i =3; while (i){ i--;NSLog(@"%@", HexColors[i]);}`

Comment: On 64 bit you will get ***  index 3 beyond bounds exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
while (HexColors[i]) ...
```

will only stop at the end of the array if there's some NULL marker there, so you have a couple of options (at least).

First, you can *put* a NULL marker there, with:

```
static NSString * const HexColors[] = {
    @"FFFFFF",
    @"FF0000",
    @"000000",
    NULL};
```

Note also there the indeterminate array size `[]` which creates an array based on the data itself. That's often preferred when you supply all the data and don't want to change too much when you add items.

Second (without adding the NULL element), you can limit your loop using a better test:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof (HexColors) / sizeof (*HexColors); i++) ...
```

That expression `sizeof (HexColors) / sizeof (*HexColors)` gives you the number of array elements in `HexColors`.

---

As an aside, the reason you're seeing *both* arrays output is because of how they're laid out in memory. The `ColorDescription` array immediately follows `HexColors` so it's as if that's just one array according to your slightly awry loop.

Then, following `ColorDescription` is a pointer (or arbitrary value interpreted as a pointer) that causes the memory fault.

```
                 +---------+
HexColors        | pointer | --> "FFFFFF" (all nul-terminated
                 | pointer | --> "FF0000"  character arrays)
                 | pointer | --> "000000"
                 +---------+
ColorDescription | pointer | --> "white"  (ditto)
                 | pointer | --> "red"
                 | pointer | --> "black"
                 +---------+
ArbitraryMemory  | ??????? | --> ???????  (except here, which
                 +---------+               could be anything)
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Obviously I missed terminating the array with NULL value. This what happens when I focus too much on objective-c, then I forget principles of C

Answer (score 1):

Change your `while (HexColors[i])` condition.

```
 while (i < arrayCount)
```

to avoid `index 3 beyond bounds`.